# recover dict from 0-d numpy array

Tags: python, dictionary, load, numpy, save

What happened is that I (by mistake) saved a dictionary with the command `numpy.save()` (no error messages shown) and now I need to recover the data in the dictionary. When I load it with `numpy.load()` it has type (`numpy.ndarray`) and is 0-d, so it is not a dictionary any more and I can't access the data in it, 0-d arrays are not index-able so doing something like

```
mydict = numpy.load('mydict')
mydict[0]['some_key']
```

doesn't work. I also tried

```
recdict = dict(mydict)
```

but that didn't work either.

Why numpy didn't warn me when I saved the dictionary with `numpy.save()`?

Is there a way to recover the data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is questionable design from numpy. Just give me my dict!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use `mydict.item()` to obtain the array element as a Python scalar.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.save('/tmp/data.npy',{'a':'Hi Mom!'})
>>> x=np.load('/tmp/data.npy')
>>> x.item()
{'a': 'Hi Mom!'}
```

Answer (score 32):

0-d arrays can be indexed using the empty tuple:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array({'x': 1})
>>> x
array({'x': 1}, dtype=object)
>>> x[()]
{'x': 1}
>>> type(x[()])
<type 'dict'>
```

Comment: what exactly going on with `[()]` mate?

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari `x[a, b, c]` is syntactic sugar for `x[(a, b, c)]`, so `x[1,2]` means getting the element at index `(1,2)` of the 2d array `x`. Because x is a 0d array, so x[()] is get the item of the 0-d arary `x`.

Comment: really helps a lot... never thought that `()` could be used for index zero length array

Answer (score 3):

It's a way to recover the `dict type` data that using `'allow_pickle=True'` and `'.tolist()'`.

 I hope it will help you.

```py
numpy.save('mydict.npy', org_dict)

# load & convert type to dict
mydict = numpy.load('mydict.npy', allow_pickle=True)
re_dict = mydict.tolist()

print('re_dict :', type(re_dict), re_dict)   # 're_dict' is '<type dict>'
```